# How to remove warning when exporting excel using PHP

Tags: php, export-to-excel

Could anyone help me on how to remove this warning when I export Excel using PHP.

> "The file you are trying to open 'MyFile.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

I completely understand the warning, saying that the Excel content has a different format.
I just want to know how/what to do to remove this warning

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFile.xls");
?>
```

Right now I only have the above codes, meaning no display yet, I'm trying to fix first this problem before populating any content. The current version installed is MS Office 2007.
I want to try PHPExcel, however I'm not sure if it can fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting the filename to `MyFile.xlsx`?

Comment: I assume you're getting the error when you are trying to open your file in Excel? Well, as you've noticed you're getting this error because you haven't got any content in the file, its obviously not going to open until you're outputting an actual Excel xls file.

When you start outputting actual Excel content then it should go away. The warning is letting you know that the format isn't actually an Excel file. When you start using PHPExcel it will/should go away.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer in PHPExcel will give you fine result. But if you want to impliment it with corePHP then here is the code to impliment.

```
<?php

function xlsBOF() {
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
}
function xlsEOF() {
    echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
}
function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
    echo pack("d", $Value);
}
function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value) {
    $L = strlen($Value);
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
    echo $Value;
} 
// prepare headers information
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export_".date("Y-m-d").".xls\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// start exporting
xlsBOF();
// first row 
xlsWriteLabel(0, 0, "id");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 1, "name");
xlsWriteLabel(0, 2, "email");
// second row 
xlsWriteNumber(1, 0, 230);
xlsWriteLabel(1, 1, "John");
xlsWriteLabel(1, 2, "john@yahoo.com");
// third row 
xlsWriteNumber(2, 0, 350);
xlsWriteLabel(2, 1, "Mark");
xlsWriteLabel(2, 2, "mark@yahoo.com");
// end exporting
xlsEOF();
exit;

?>
```

Reference from http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/php-export-mysql-data-to-xls-file

Answer (score 1):

You are probably saving CSV file with XLS extension. 
Change Content-type to text/csv and file extension to .csv, it opens by default in Excel and should prevent displaying this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are exporting an excel-document?

If so: try the folowing headers:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyFile.xls"');
```

This doesn't give errors with my MS Office 2007 installation

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this warning.

Then i have used PHPExcel.

May be help you. http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Or use following code :

//  Include PHPExcel_IOFactory

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

//  Read your Excel workbook
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    //  Insert row data array into your database of choice here
}
```

reference:

http://www.grad.clemson.edu/assets/php/phpexcel/documentation/api/__filesource/fsource_phpexcel__phpexceliofactory.php.html